# Difference between string and string? in c#

Tags: c#, .net

In c#, the string type is inherently nullable, right? This morning I was working with the `Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable()` method, and noticed it returns type `string?`. Is the `?` added to the return type redundant, and just there to indicate that it returns null when there are no environment variables that match the variable name you asked for? Or is there a more significant difference between `string` and `string?` in .net/c#?

Comment: Just look at the docs: *Returns: The value of the environment variable specified by variable, **or null** if the environment variable is not found.*

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/builtin-types/nullable-reference-types#nullable-references-and-static-analysis

Comment: >Is the ? added to the return type redundant, and just there to indicate that it returns null when there are no environment variables that match the variable name you asked for? 

Your statement is correct here. It's a declarative mark used by the compiler to help in finding potential null reference errors.

Comment: @DmitriyPolyanskiy That doc is exactly what I was looking for. Very cool to know. Thanks!